# Requiring PhantomJS within a Mocha test

Tags: requirejs, phantomjs, mocha.js

I'm trying to get off the ground with mocha-phantomjs and I seem to be hitting a snag with regards to require.  I was hoping other sets of eyes can see what I'm doing wrong.

```
$ mocha-phantomjs test/index.html

My Site
1) server should be running
Error: Script error for: webpage
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

The files in question are fairly small:

https://gist.github.com/cobaltroad/6675855

Here's the spec script in particular:

*test.spec.js*

```
describe("My Site", function() {
    it("server should be running", function(done) {
        require(['webpage'], function(webpage) {
            var page = webpage.create();
            page.open("http://localhost:8080/", function() {
                var title = page.evaluate(function () {
                    return document.title;
                });
                title.should.eql('My Title');
                console.log("Title: " + title);
                phantom.exit();
                done();
            });
        });
    }); // server should be running
});
```

I've tried various forms of define/require and I haven't been able to get it quite right.

Comment: Are there any 404s or other HTTP errors? It looks like you are `require`ing the `'webpage'` module from a browser-loaded script, when it possibly should be only used as a node module.

Comment: Can you include the `webpage` script?

Comment: `webpage` comes from phantomjs.